# Symfony 2 - always one role active

Tags: symfony, roles

I am new to Symfony 2 and I need to set up user roles. What would be the best way to customize standard functionality in order to have several roles for the user to choose from but only one active at a time.

Comment: So you don't use a [role hierarchy](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles)? With role hierachy an user can have one role and inherited roles which is simpler, for example a user with `ROLE_ADMIN` will be able to access all the other roles.

Comment: User has several roles and it's fine. What you mean with "one active a time?". If I am a logged user what is your logic to change my role to another one and make it active?

Comment: If user is logged then he can select one from several roles: ROLE_MASTER, ROLE_SECTION_ADMIN, ROLE_DEALER, ROLE_SECTION_DEALER. Then user can change his selected role everytime. Each role has own  right, what it can do.